# I want be sure before install ubuntu desktop on laptop

Tags: graphics

Ok,this my question.If my laptop can run window vista,can i run ubuntu desktop 14.04 as well.Just want be sure.

Comment: If you want to be **sure**, you're better off looking at the actual specs of your hardware rather than relying on a rule of thumb based on what other software can run on it.

Comment: Best way is to just run off the ubuntu DVD in live mode (the default Ubuntu DVD iso images that you download will boot in live mode). Play around with the live mode and when satisfied then go on to install. Of course, before install you will want to follow other guidelines like backup data etc.

Comment: yes ofcourse it can but be sure you have seperate drives for both of them and to be sure give your hardware configuration

Answer (score 3):

Go see for yourself.

[Download](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/) an Ubuntu Desktop ISO, create a [bootable USB stick](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) or [burn a DVD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-windows), boot it up and select "Try Ubuntu".

This will not alter your hard drive or install anything, Ubuntu will be run from the installation medium. If you like it, just click on the "install" icon on your desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Please check requirements in this link with your laptop

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements